# Prove this inequality $a^4+b^4+c^4+9\ge 4(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, substitution, buffalo-way

let $a,b,c>0$ and such $abc=1$, show that

$$a^4+b^4+c^4+9\ge 4(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$$

Schur inequality 
$$a^4+b^4+c^4\ge \sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2)-abc(a+b+c)$$
It suffices to show that
$$\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2)+9\ge 4(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+abc(a+b+c)$$

Comment: set $a=x/y,b=y/z,c=z/x$

Comment: Your last inequality is not true, so you need a stronger version of Schur in addition to some bunching, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=x^3$, $b=y^3$ and $c=z^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that:
$$x^{12}+y^{12}+z^{12}+9x^4y^4z^4\geq4xyz(x^6y^3+y^6z^3+z^6x^3)$$
Let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$, $z=x+v$ and $x=k\sqrt{uv}$.

Thus, 
$$x^{12}+y^{12}+z^{12}+9x^4y^4z^4-4xyz(x^6y^3+y^6z^3+z^6x^3)=$$
$$=12(u^2-uv+v^2)x^{10}+4(25u^3-36u^2v-9uv^2+25v^3)x^9+$$
$$+36(10u^4-12u^3v-5u^2v^2-3uv^3+10v^4)x^8+$$
$$+12(59u^5-44u^4v-52u^3v^2-10u^2v^3-11uv^4+59v^5)x^7+$$
$$+(896u^6-336u^5v-786u^4v^2-416u^3v^3-30u^2v^4-84uv^5+896v^6)x^6+$$
$$+4(197u^7-28u^6v-126u^5v^2-131u^4v^3-26u^3v^4-7uv^6+197v^7)x^5+$$
$$+(495u^8-16u^7v-168u^6v^2-336u^5v^3-131u^4v^4-4uv^7+495v^8)x^4+$$
$$+4(55u^9-6u^7v^2-28u^6v^3-21u^5v^4+55v^9)x^3+$$
$$+2(33u^{10}-8u^7v^3-14u^6v^4+33v^{10})x^2+4(3u^{11}-u^7v^4+3v^{11})x+u^{12}+v^{12}\geq$$
$$\geq u^6v^6(12k^{10}+16k^9-23k^8-38k^7+81k^6+263k^5+317k^4+215k^3+87k^2+19k+2)\geq0$$
Done!